# Command Line Rendering - "cannot render, no camera"

Tags: rendering

I'm rendering a few scenes with command line and it works fine with most of them. But there is one scene where I get the following error: "cannot render, no camera". I can manually render it because there is indeed a camera in the scene.

I erased everything that could cause trouble ending up with only a cube and a camera. And all properties match with the working scenes but it's still not working with this file.

[image]

Comment: to be sure to reproduce, share your CLI command arguments...

Comment: cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"

blender -b C:\Users\me\Desktop\batch\01.blend -o C:\Users\me\Desktop\batch\_01_ -f 1

Comment: Second answer on the question linked to, above.

Comment: @RayMairlot is right, the scene properties show no camera selected...